# Joining Two Tables, but how to show all results?

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have two table structures like these:

```
episodes (
episode_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
episode_series_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
episode_series_season TINYINT(2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
episode_series_episode SMALLINT(5) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
episode_title VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
PRIMARY KEY (episode_id),
KEY series_id (episode_series_id),
KEY episode_series_season (episode_series_season),
KEY episode_series_episode (episode_series_episode)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

watchlist (
watchlist_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
watchlist_user_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
watchlist_series_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
watchlist_series_episode_id MEDIUMINT(8) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
watchlist_status TINYINT(1) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
PRIMARY KEY (watchlist_id),
KEY watchlist_series_episode_id (watchlist_series_episode_id),
KEY watchlist_series_id (watchlist_series_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;"
```

I want to join these two, and show all results.

This didn't help me:

```
SELECT e.*, w.* FROM episodes e, watchlist w WHERE e.episode_series_id='1' AND e.episode_series_season='1' AND w.watchlist_user_id='1'
```

I'm using this query, but as usual, it shows only matching columns (30+ lines in episodes table, 2 lines in watchlist table)

```
SELECT e.*,w.* FROM episodes e INNER JOIN watchlist w ON e.episode_id=w.watchlist_series_episode_id WHERE e.episode_series_id='1' AND e.episode_series_season='1' AND w.watchlist_user_id='1'
```

But it only shows 2 lines (as it should).

```
episode_id  episode_series_id   episode_series_season   episode_series_episode  episode_title   watchlist_id    watchlist_user_id   watchlist_series_id watchlist_series_episode_id watchlist_status
1                 1                       1                      1                    Pilot            1                 1                    1                    1                        0
2                 1                       1                      2                 Paternity           2                 1                    1                    2                        0
```

But I want to show all matching results (I want to select all columns from these two table, list episodes, if there's a match from watchlist I want to fill data from watchlist column, else they should be null)

I want to get results like this:

```
episode_id  episode_series_id   episode_series_season   episode_series_episode  episode_title   watchlist_id    watchlist_user_id   watchlist_series_id watchlist_series_episode_id watchlist_status
1                 1                       1                      1                    Pilot            1                 1                    1                    1                        0
2                 1                       1                      2                 Paternity           2                 1                    1                    2                        0 
3                 1                       1                      3                  whatever1         null             null                 null                 null                      null 
4                 1                       1                      4                  whatever2         null             null                 null                 null                      null 
5                 1                       1                      5                  whatever3         null             null                 null                 null                      null
```

I couldn't put this together. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's what `LEFT JOIN` is for, instead of `INNER JOIN`

```
SELECT e.*,w.* 
FROM episodes e 
LEFT JOIN watchlist w 
   ON e.episode_id=w.watchlist_series_episode_id AND w.watchlist_user_id='1'
WHERE e.episode_series_id='1' 
AND e.episode_series_season='1'
```

- The condition on `w.watchlist_user_id` must also appear in the ON clause.

Comment: output is exactly the same with LEFT JOIN with same inner joining query.

Comment: @Arda - Did you also move the condition on w.watchlist_user_id to the ON clause?

Comment: @Arda - The WHERE clause filters the result, no matter what type of JOIN you use - records with `user_id = NULL` do not satisfy the condition so they are not returned by the query. The ON clause defines how to attach records from table b to records from table a (so only records with user_id = 1 are joined).

Answer (score 0):

Just use `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT * FROM episodes e 
LEFT JOIN watchlist w ON e.episode_id = w.watchlist_series_episode_id 
WHERE e.episode_series_id='1' 
AND e.episode_series_season='1' 
AND w.watchlist_user_id='1'
```

Comment: output is same with this. as @Galz's comment, w.watchlist_user_id='1' should be in ON clause.

Answer (score 0):

Change your `INNER JOIN` to an `OUTER JOIN` or `LEFT JOIN` (which is `LEFT OUTER JOIN`).

Answer (score 0):

Try having left join episode on the left and watchlist on the right .... It will return all the episodes and corresponding watch - list if any ...